# Quickest way to rewrite urls to lowercase?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way, preferably with .htaccess to rewrite a url when a user types in something with a capital.

For example, the url could be website.com/pagename

and the usertypes in website.com/PageName or website.com/PAGENAME

Whats the best way to do with without slowing down page load?

Answer (score 2):

You can either do an HTTP redirect (via Apache):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

or do the processing in PHP:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

HTTP redirection isn't really as efficient as the PHP solution.

Comment: Worth noting that RewriteMap doesn't usually work with shared hosts